# Scalar Multiplication using NAF method

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I am learning about Elliptic curve scalar multiplications and I am on NAF, and I am trying to figure out the concept.

What I understand is if I have `K=27` with using NAF the binary looks like this `100-10-1` then the scalar multiplication process like this: `2(2(2(2(2P))-P))-P` which is 5DBL and 2ADD.

My questions is if want to scalar `K=27` it means the steps like this:

1- 2P (0 bit)

2- 4P (0 bit)

3- 8P-P=7P (-1 bit)

4- 14P (0 bit)

5- 28P-P=27P (-1 bit)

My issue is how can I calculate `28P` then minus `one P` and my group only `27P` my group is like this:

```
 1     3    10
 2     7    12
 3    19     5
 4    17     3
 5     9    16
 6    12     4
 7    11     3
 8    13    16
 9     0     1
10     6     4
11    18    20
12     5     4
13     1     7
14     4     0
15     1    16
16     5    19
17    18     3
18     6    19
19     0    22
20    13     7
21    11    20
22    12    19
23     9     7
24    17    20
25    19    18
26     7    11
27     3    13
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is how can I calculate `28P` then minus one `P`

The issue that appears to be confusing you is that the order of the curve you picked happens to be 28, and hence `28P` happens to be the "point at infinity", which does not correspond to any specific $(x, y)$ coordinates.

In spite of that, it is a well defined 'point' (even if it's not a solution to the curve equation), with well defined addition and subtraction operations; if we designate $I$ as the point at infinity, then we have $I+X = X+I = X-I = X$ and $I-X = -X$, for any point $X$.

If you're using an EC library to do your point operations, it should handle it correctly internally.

Comment: Actually I modified a code in Matlab, but can i resolve it in matlab code if reached to `Infinity` then instead of `14P doubling` then make `13P doubling = 26P+P=27P` ?  What is EC library I can use it in matlab to resolve the issue?

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: I am unfamiliar with Matlab, and so I cannot help you there

Comment: No issue Bro, you give me where is the issue and that's enough I hope can get the resolution..Thanks :) I solved it by checking if reach to infinity then minus 1P then continue and the result is correct.2